# Search text in file and print all text

Tags: python

okay. you didnt understand anything from the title. let me explain.

now ı have a file. There is some text in this file. for example "jack.123 jackie.321"

I want to check if the word jack exists in the file and ı wanna print "jack.123".

its my problem. ı didnt print all text.

```
def append(name,password):
  f = open("myfile.txt", "w")
  f.write("{},{}".format(name,password))

append("jack",".123")
append("jackie" , ".321")
f = open("myfile.txt" ,"r")
if "jack" in f.read():
    print("query found")
```

Comment: if you didn't find your answer could you share the text file you are working with?

Comment: Perhaps you want to read and write whole lines to the file, so you have discrete records.

Comment: What would be the desired output if you're searching for 'jack' and the file contains 'lumberjack'?

Comment: "jack,123" ı wanna it

Comment: @HasanCb So let's be clear... If you're searching for 'jack' and the file contains 'lumberjack.123' you want to print 'jack,123'. Are you sure?

Comment: no so jack is something like username and 123 its your username code. and ı append a "."
now if ı enter lumberjack, ı wanna print lumberjack.123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file and read all its contents then split on whitespace. That effectively gives you all the words in the file.

Iterate over the list of words checking to see if a word starts with the name you're searching for followed by '.'.

Note that there may be more than one occurrence so build a list.

```
def find_name(filename, name):
    if not name[-1] == '.':
        name += '.'
    found = []
    with open(filename) as myfile:
        for word in myfile.read().split():
            if word.startswith(name):
                found.append(word)
    return found

print(*find_name('myfile.txt', 'jack'))
```

Comment: its just print "[]"

Comment: @HasanCb In that case, your file doesn't contain what you say it does

Comment: hah. its jack.123

Comment: thanks but ı dont get it clearly. can you explain step by step

Comment: ı am talking about your code. it worked but ı dont get it

Comment: @HasanCb Did you read my explanation at the beginning of the answer?

Comment: actually no. :D I'm reading your explanation now.

Comment: well thanks. ı get it clearly now.

Answer (score 0):

```
def new_pass(name, passwd):
    "creates file and write name and passwd to it"
    with open("myfile1.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(name + "." + passwd + "\n")


new_pass("jack", "123")
new_pass("jack", "183")
new_pass("jack", "129")
new_pass("jack", "223")


def check_word(file, word):
    """checks if a word exists and returns its first occurence """
    with open(file) as f:
        l = f.read().split("\n")
    for i in l:
        if i.startswith(word):
            print("query found")
            return i


print(check_word("myfile1.txt", "jack"))
```

Comment: well its also good. thanks :d

Comment: It is my first time contributing and it might not be the best code but I hope it helps. In your code using "append" as a function name is not really advisable as it a known list method in python, and also opening a file in write mode means that each time you write to the file the new words you adding will overwrite what is there before, that is why I opted for the append mode ("a"), and it is also advisable to use the "with" context manager so that you dont have to worry about closing the file incase you forgot about it. Thank you for the opportunity to contribute

Answer (score -1):

In python you can do it like that :

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()

if "jack" in data:
    print("jack")
```

If I understood uncorrectly let me know

Comment: ı dont wanna print "jack"

Comment: ı wanna print "jack.123"